# In any triangle, $b^2\sin(2\gamma)+c^2\sin(2\beta)=2ac\sin(\beta)$

Tags: triangles

Prove that any triangle, $b^2\sin(2\gamma)+c^2\sin(2\beta)=2ac\sin(\beta)$.

Hello. I am very stuck on this problem. How could I go? Expand the double-angle sine but don't get to anything simpler. Also use that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma = 180$ to use identities of the type $\sin(2\pi-x) = -\sin(x)$ but also don't get to something simpler.
Some hint?

Comment: It may be helpful for you if you show your work.

Comment: "Expand the double-angle sine but don't get to anything simpler." Don't you? Writing $\sin\gamma$ in terms of side lengths and the area (whatever symbol you use for it), and $\cos\gamma$ in terms of side lengths with the cosine rule, should be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint (use double-angle formula to expand the left side first):
$1$. By law of sines, we have $b \sin(\gamma)=c \sin(\beta)$;
$2$. Construct the height of edge $a$ and prove $a=b \cos(\gamma)+c \cos(\beta)$.

Comment: Thanks.

$b^2\sin(2\gamma)+c^2\sin(2\beta)=2ac\sin(\beta)\\
(b\sin\gamma)(b\cos(\gamma)+(c\sin\beta)(c\cos\beta)=ac\sin\beta\\
c\sin\beta)(b\cos\gamma+c\cos\beta)=ac\sin(\beta)\\
b\cos\gamma+c\cos\beta=a$

Comment: @eraldcoil Well done, although it's best to write proofs forwards, so to speak.